# Unable to print statement when 0 value is returned using awk/bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

awk to print on expression returning 0 value

Team, I am trying to print a message based on return value (0 or non0)

If return is a non0 my below expression holds good. But when return is 0, I get no print execution. Any hint how to tackle this?

```
$ ▶ echo $NON_ZERO_MATCH
team.com/gpu\s\+\([1-9][0-9]*\)\s\+[1-9][0-9]*
$ ▶ kubectl describe node 123 | sed -n 's%'"$NON_ZERO_MATCH"'%\1%p' | awk '$0 > 0 {print "team User pods Found and gpus used are:", $0;} $0 = 0 {print "team Users pods NotFound and gpus used are:", $0;}'
team Users pods in execution and gpus used are:   8
$ ▶ kubectl describe node 321 | sed -n 's%'"$NON_ZERO_MATCH"'%\1%p' | awk '$0 < 1 {print "team User pods Found and gpus used are:", $0;} $0 = 0 {print "team Users pods NotFound and gpus used are:", $0;}'
<< get no output

Output:
Expected: "team User pods NotFound and gpus used are:0"
Actual: [nothing]
```

The entire output to describe node is here
`https://github.com/ctxrag/dev/blob/stack-overflow-pull-pod-info/kubectl_node_describe.yaml`

```
$ ▶ uname -a
Linux dtlu16 4.15.0-88-generic #88~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 12 04:19:15 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
dtlu @ dtlu16 ~/code/team/ai-infra (test-bala)
└─ $ ▶ sed --version | grep 4.2
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

example output:
My command is expected to look only at the left position decimal and output that for below it should output 8 and ignore 0 on right.

`team.com/gpu 8 0`

output: team User pods Found and gpus used are:8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your regex uses syntax that is not guaranteed to be supported in sed. `\s` is not part of the BRE or ERE specifications. If you're going to use GNUisms in your question, also specify the specific versions of the software you're using (version of sed, etc)... or better, just refine the code to work on all POSIX-compliant platforms.

Comment: added version info. can you paste a suggested answer or whatever seems good to you?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `END{}` block of `awk`, if you can show results of `kubectl describe node 123` one can easily write in `awk` itself no need of `sed` and multiple pipe.

**For instance Example :**

```
your_command | awk 'END{print "team User pods NotFound and gpus used are: " $0+0}'`
```

**In your case**

```
kubectl describe node 123 | sed -n 's%'"$NON_ZERO_MATCH"'%\1%p' |  awk 'END{print "team User pods NotFound and gpus used are: " $0+0}'
```

**Here is test results:**

```
$ echo 1234 | awk 'END{print "team User pods NotFound and gpus used are: " $0+0}'
team User pods NotFound and gpus used are: 1234

$ cat /dev/null | awk 'END{print "team User pods NotFound and gpus used are: " $0+0}'
team User pods NotFound and gpus used are: 0
```

Comment: Does not work 
```
 kubectl describe node 123 | sed -n 's%'"$NON_ZERO_MATCH"'%\1%p' |  awk 'END{print "team User pods NotFound and gpus used are: " $0+0}'
sed: -e expression #1, char 49: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
team User pods NotFound and gpus used are: 0
dtlu @ dtlu16 ~
└─ $ ▶ echo $NON_ZERO_MATCH
team.com/gpus+([1-9][0-9]*)s+[1-9][0-9]*
```

Comment: I have uploaded entire output to describe node above in my question

Answer (score 0):

I played with your sed command and this works for me:

```
cat kubectl_node_describe.yaml | sed -rn 's/.*gpu[[:space:]]+([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+[0-9]+/\1/p'
```

Note that your file has test.com in it, but you hardcoded for team.com, so that was not matching. I removed that to put .* and then rewrote sed a little more. I didn't look at the awk part.

Comment: this seems to work: can you explain me what is /\1 doing? I know its value to be substituted but not clear.

Comment: My command is expected to look only at the left position decimal and output that for below it should output 8 and ignore 0 on right.
`  team.com/gpu                               8                  0`